# How do I install sv.net/classic with wine on macOS?

Tags: macos, wine

How do I install [sv.net/classic](http://www.itsg.de/svnet_downloads.html) on macOS? That's a program you can use to submit information about your employee for german general social welfare insurance purposes and records.

I don't want to buy licenses for VirtualBox and Windows.

The [ITSG support page about linux and macOS](http://www.itsg.de/svnet_Weitere_Informationen_sv_net_classic_unter_Linux_und_MAC_OS.html) gives me a hint that I could use wine for this purpose, but it doesn't give a detailed step-by-step guide for wine newbies like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download and install the current version of [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org) (as of this writing, it is version 2.7.11).
2. Download and execute the "Installer for Wine staging" from the [wine macOS download page](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/download.html).
3. Execute “Wine Staging” and execute the next steps in the console which opens.
4. Get [winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks#Getting_winetricks)

   ```
   wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
   chmod +x winetricks
   ```
5. Install cab extract, which is required by the installation of jet40 afterwards (this assumes that you already installed the packet manager brew):

   ```
   brew install cabextract
   ```
6. Install the dependencies mentioned on the sv.net support page:

   ```
   sh winetricks mdac28
   sh winetricks jet40
   sh winetricks vb6run
   sh winetricks ie8
   sh winetricks wininet
   ```
7. Download [Setup.exe](http://download.gkvnet-ag.de/Setup.exe) from the [sv.net download page](http://www.itsg.de/svnet_downloads.html) on the ITSG web site.
8. `cd` into the directory where you downloaded the installer and run the installer in wine, keeping the default settings :

   ```
    wine Setup.exe
   ```
9. Configure wine:

   ```
   winecfg
   ```

   In tab “libraries”, add ole32, oleaut32 and olepro32
10. Start sv.net:

    ```
     wine "C:\Program Files\svnet\svnet.exe"
    ```
11. In sv.net, under the “Info” menu, click the “Einstellungen” button to set up the network connection and select the “Direct” connection mode. The network test will fail, but it’s OK, the further operations will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think installation with winebottler is easier.
http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. Please explain why the linked page is relevant and how the OP can use the software described their to solve the problem described in the question.